# Install lamp-server using tasksel

Tags: server, lamp, zend

I recently have started to work on ubuntu for web development.

Initially I installed Zend server on my Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS. But later I decided to go with "lamp-server", so I un-installed the Zend server by running

```
/usr/local/zend/bin/uninstall.sh
```

as shown in  http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-6/content/deb_uninstalling_zend_server.htm

Now I want to install lamp server using tasksel by running following command

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

but I am having trouble installing it. I get error page when I go to localhost in a browser.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

### **EDITS FROM DISCUSSION IN COMMENTS**

**EDIT 1**

After running `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` I get this message:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'apache2-utils' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libwrap0' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libnet-daemon-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libclass-isa-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libswitch-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libcap2' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-template-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libdbi-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2.2-bin' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libdbd-mysql-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapr1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1-ldap' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-mpm-prefork' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libplrpc-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'tcpd' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2.2-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'ssl-cert' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'perl-modules' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libmysqlclient18' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-mysql' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-cli' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-common' for task 'lamp-server'
libapr1 is already the newest version.
libaprutil1 is already the newest version.
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 is already the newest version.
libaprutil1-ldap is already the newest version.
libcap2 is already the newest version.
libclass-isa-perl is already the newest version.
libdbd-mysql-perl is already the newest version.
libdbi-perl is already the newest version.
libhtml-template-perl is already the newest version.
libnet-daemon-perl is already the newest version.
libplrpc-perl is already the newest version.
libswitch-perl is already the newest version.
libwrap0 is already the newest version.
tcpd is already the newest version.
apache2-mpm-prefork is already the newest version.
apache2-utils is already the newest version.
apache2.2-bin is already the newest version.
apache2.2-common is already the newest version.
libapache2-mod-php5 is already the newest version.
libmysqlclient18 is already the newest version.
mysql-client-5.5 is already the newest version.
mysql-client-core-5.5 is already the newest version.
mysql-common is already the newest version.
mysql-server-5.5 is already the newest version.
mysql-server-core-5.5 is already the newest version.
perl is already the newest version.
perl-modules is already the newest version.
php5-cli is already the newest version.
php5-common is already the newest version.
php5-mysql is already the newest version.
ssl-cert is already the newest version.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 mysql-server
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 348 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/13.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 146 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Selecting previously unselected package apache2.
(Reading database ... 182247 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking apache2 (from .../apache2_2.2.22-1ubuntu1.5_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Setting up apache2 (2.2.22-1ubuntu1.5) ...
```

---

**EDIT 2**
It seems lamp-server has been installed correctly but when I go to localhost I get this error ' Unable to connect Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.'

I tried to restart apache2 using `sudo service apache2 restart` only to face this error:

> Syntax error on line 239 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf: No such file or directory
>   Action 'configtest' failed.
>   The Apache error log may have more information.
>   ...fail!

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` and paste any errors you may encounter here.

Comment: @Parto I did not get any error after running the suggested command. I get a very long message, last portion of the message is as follows

Comment: You can paste the message at http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and provide the link here or edit your question and include it directly. We need to see that message to know whats going on.

Comment: @Parto here is the link http://paste.ubuntu.com/7335326/

Comment: It seems lamp server has been installed correctly. What message do you get when you go to http://localhost/

Comment: I get this message :-   
        Unable to connect
      
       Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14151/discussion-between-parto-and-user11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall apache2 and reinstall it again. It seems there is an issue with your apache2 config files. Run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To confirm it has been removed, run: `which apache2` it should return a blank line or run `sudo service apache2 start` it should return 'apache2: unrecognized service'

Now to reinstall it again run:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Localhost should now be working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the install in this sequence:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install tasksel`
3. `sudo tasksel install lamp-server`